# How to use events of vue-tel-input?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I've installed  **vue-tel-input**  component and included it. I want to use the validate event tha's found in [a link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-tel-input)! but I can't. How to use it in the compoennt?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have your tried with Info from their page ?
In main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueTelInput from 'vue-tel-input'

Vue.use(VueTelInput)
```

and then use it as component

```
<template>
  <vue-tel-input v-model="phone"></vue-tel-input>
<template>
```

Comment: In this page there is a list of events one of them is called **validate** How to use this event with the component?

Answer (score 7):

The events are regular vue component events.
You can listen for these events as outlined here in the vue docs.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Listening-to-Child-Components-Events

For example, to use the validate event you would add a listener to the vue-tel-input component.

The listener will automatically pass the arguments to your method.

```
// In your template
<vue-tel-input
  v-model="yourModel"
  @validate="yourValidationMethod"
/>

// In your component methods

yourValidationMethod: function ({ number, isValid, country }) {
    // Do stuff with the arguments passed by the vue-tel-input component
},
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
// in methods
phoneObject(object) {
  console.log(object.valid);
},
```

```html
// in template
<vue-tel-input
  v-model="yourModel"
  @validate="phoneObject"
></vue-tel-input>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll try the answer to be beginner friendly, as I remember myself struggling with it.

You can use the `@validate` event. It fires when the correctness of the phone number changes (from true to false or vice-versa) and when the component is mounted. [- from official docs](https://vue-tel-input.iamstevendao.com/documentation/events.html#validate-phoneobject-object)

In your template:

```
<vue-tel-input v-model="phone" @validate="phoneObject"></vue-tel-input>
<span v-if="isValid">valid</span>
<span v-else>not valid</span>
```

Add this method in your script:

```
phoneObject: function(object) {
    this.isValid = object.valid;
}
```

**Example:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: () => ({
    phone: null,
    isValid: null,
  }),
  methods: {
    phoneObject: function(object) {
      console.log(object);
      if (object.valid === true) {
        this.isValid = true;
      } else {
        this.isValid = false;
      }
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>

<link href="https://unpkg.com/vue-tel-input/dist/vue-tel-input.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-tel-input@5.12.0/dist/vue-tel-input.umd.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <vue-tel-input v-model="phone" @validate="phoneObject"></vue-tel-input>
  <div>
    <span v-if="isValid">valid</span>
    <span v-else>not valid</span>
  </div>

</div>
```